# Making ng-donut clickable AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, donut-chart

I am pretty new to this. I am using https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngDonut to create donut on my website. I am able to get it up and running now my next step is to make it clickable. Lets take this example http://ng-donut.herokuapp.com/

Suppose if I want to make it in a way when a user click on the donut partition the it becomes highlighted with corresponding row on the left hand side pane. I am not sure how to achieve it.

Can anyone throw some light on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fork and modify the project they have https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngDonut#mouse-events

Using the click handler and the model object I imagine you can find the corresponding row and set a property on it that causes it to be highlighted (ng-class).  For the pie itself to highlight you may be able to make use of the colours property mentioned in the README.md there.

If that doesn't work out would need to fork the project and take a look at where it's using those colours to draw the pie with D3 and have it modify them based on the last one that was clicked on.